# Javascript Array Integer Array Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, parseint

I have a project in which I need to loop through an array of floats. The objective of this project is to format each individual float to this specific format ".XXX" where X is the number. If the number leads with a 0 then it should be omitted. For example: `0.2867` should be formatted to `.286` or if you have a number like `1.2` it should be formatted to `1.200`. If the element in the array is not a number say for example "-" then it should be formatted to `.000`.

Below is my code for this project thus far but I am stuck:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var statsArray = [0.2867, 0.833, 1.576, 0.19, 0.688, 0.22, 0.572, .167, 0.643, 0.921, "-", "-", 0.222, 1.466789, 0.1, 0.714, 1.115];

function formatter()
{
    var numElements = statsArray.length;

    for (var m=0; m <= numElements; m++) 
    {
        var arrayElement = statsArray[m];

        console.log ("original element is " + arrayElement);

        arrayElement = parseInt(arrayElement, 10);

        console.log ("after parseInt element is " + arrayElement);

        arrayElement = arrayElement.toPrecision(3);

        console.log ("after toPrecision element is " + arrayElement);

    }
}

formatter();

});
```

Any suggestions on where to go next or what I am missing would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could push `arrayElement` to a new array, return the array from `formatter()` call

Comment: My want to use different variables other than `arrayElement` for some steps. Using `parseInt()` will remove the decimal values, leaving only the whole numbers, `0` or `1`, for `.toPrecision()`.

Comment: It's not clear what's meant by "format" here. For example, a leading zero in a float can't be "formatted" away unless "formatting" means you're converting the number to a string for display. If that is what it means, then format each number to a string first and operate on the parts of it that way.

Comment: You can determine if the value is a number or other using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and get consistent numbers of decimals using [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var statsArray = [12.2,0.2867, 0.833, 1.576, 0.19, 0.688, 0.22, 0.572, .167, 0.643, 0.921, "-", "-", 0.222, 1.466789, 0.1, 0.714, 1.115];

statsArray = statsArray.map(function(number){
    number = Number(number).toFixed(3);

    if(number === 'NaN') return '.000';

    return number[0] === '0'? number.slice(1) : number
});
console.log(statsArray);
```

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/oLjPvX

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNaN` to check for `"-"`; remove `parseInt` and `=` at `<=` operator; create an array to push values to, return array from `formatter()`.

Edit, Updated

As suggested by [@JonathanLonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692473/javascript-array-integer-array-format/37692581#comment62861322_37692473), also, try substituting `.toFixed()` for `.toPrecision()` to return expected result.

```js
var statsArray = [0.2867, 0.833, 1.576, 0.19, 0.688, 0.22, 0.572, .167, 0.643, 0.921, "-", "-", 0.222, 1.466789, 0.1, 0.714, 1.115];

function formatter(arr) {
  for (var m = 0, res = []; m < arr.length; m++) {
    var arrayElement = statsArray[m];
    console.log("original element is " + arrayElement);
    if (!isNaN(arrayElement)) {
      res.push(arrayElement.toFixed(3))
    } else {
      if (arrayElement === "-") {
        res.push(".000")
      }
    }
  }
  return res
}

var result = formatter(statsArray);
console.log(result)
```